# Same RewriteCond and multiple RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got in my application some review rules here's example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)-street\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?street=%1&$1=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)-street\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?street=%1 [L]
```

I expect if I type: example-street.example.com/type/param.html that it use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?street=%1&$1=$2 [L]
```

but unfortunately it use less specified one.

What should I add/change in my code to get expected result?

**EDIT**
I want to achive this result:

`example-street.example.com/type/param.html -> index.php?street=example&type=param`
`example-street.example.com/whateverelse -> index.php?street=example`

Comment: Do you want to redirect `example-street.example.com/type/param.html` to `index.php`

Comment: @SahilGulati example-street.example.com/type/param.html -> index.php?street=example&type=param

Comment: @SahilGulati example-street.example.com/whateverelse -> index.php?street=example

Comment: Provide the unwanted output you get. Also, I suspect that your two capture groups are more greedy than you think. Try describing in prose what the capture groups are supposed to capture.

Comment: @J.Marciniak Can you check whether it is working fine or not?

Answer (score 0):

Check this, hope it will work fine.

[Check .htaccess here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/type/param.html$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z]+)\-([a-z]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\.html$ /index.php?%2=%1&$1=$2    [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-z]+)\-([a-z]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?%2=%1    [R=301,L,QSA]
```